# LinkedIn API - I dont understand how they want the urls formatted

Tags: api, rest, linkedin-api

I am looking at this documentation page for LinkedIn API:https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api

They have an example there: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api

I am trying to send them a url like this:

```
/people/id=297823:(connections)
```

because they seem to recommend that under the "Selecting the amount of detail returned" section, but it gives this error:

```
LinkedIn::Errors::NotFoundError: (404): Not Found
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong with the url?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It returns NOT FOUND because `297823` is not a valid profile id. Try with a valid id,

e.g.

`nbqwYraDfd` is linked id of my linkedin profile, so below code works for me.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=nbqwYraDfd:(connections)
```

*p.s. notice that you need to authenticate in order to get this work.*

**Edit:** (after comment)

To know your id, do this,

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id)
```

Use [this](https://developer.linkedin.com/rest-console/) to play with linkedin api,

Comment: +1 - as the url is right, but the part about the 404 should be revised. I get 401 using 297823:  http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=297823:(connections)

Comment: @Jashwant hmm, here is an example of my profle: http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=16268324&trk=tab_pro -- I thought the id=16268324 was the id.  Is it not? How/where should I get the real id?

Comment: @Joshwant doing other queries with this user_id works...possibly this type of query requires a different user id?

Comment: @Joshwant btw, how did you get this id nbqwYraDfd? Is it mine? How do I get other peoples id in that format?  Thanks again!

Comment: @jmort253, it returns 401 (unauthorise) on browser (because the call is unauthorised) and 404 (not found) on console/api becoz you authenticate it there but there's no profile with that id :)

Comment: @GeekedOut, I've updated my answer to reflect how to get that id.

Comment: What about authentication? How is the url formatted exactly if you include access token?

Comment: @Jashwant - any clue on this please? I really need this getting work...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985535/linkedin-share-api-gives-a-null-response

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the v1 from the beginning of the url:

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=abcdefg
```

This assumes you're trying to get the public profile for a specific member.

> **Choosing public or standard profile**
>
> The URL to retrieve the standard and public profiles are the same. To return a public profile, simply add  :public to the end of the profile. Without that, the call will return a standard profile.

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url={public-profile-url}:public
```

You need to authenticate in order to get the *standard* profile, which is the url *without* the :public.  With :public, you don't need to authenticate.

Also, don't forget to escape the profile URL!

Comment: thanks, the api appends the v1, so I have to get the part after the v1 right, but for some reason, it returns 404.

Comment: this is the error: LinkedIn::Errors::NotFoundError: (404): Not Found

Comment: yeah I authenticate inside my app.  Also, doing other queries with this user_id works...maybe this type of query requires a different user id....hmm

Answer (score 1):

The userID for the API is an encrypted string which is unique for your application.  The LinkedIn API is not intended to be used with information from the website (because it encourages data scraping).  You need to do a search with the API (or find the member by some other means, such as connections on the current user) and then use the ID you receive back from that request for subsequent profile requests.

Things to remember:

- The ID for a member is a string that's unique for your application key
- An ID for a member retrieved via the website will not work
- An ID for a member retrieved via another application will not work